# How do I match this string

Tags: regex

Quick question. How do I match

```
site.com/characters/
```

and not match

```
site.com/characters/characters2
```

Attempt:

```
site.com/[a-zA-Z]+/?
```

Comment: What happened when you tried the regex? That seems pretty fine. I guess a `$` at the end would help.

Comment: If your problem is that it matched the *part of* the second string, you need to add an [string end anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick answer:

Your approach is perfectly fine. You should have used the `$` (terminating character) to specify the match.

```
site.com/[A-z]+/?$
```

Comment: I bet that I tried it and it didn't work till now. Thank you for the answer .

Comment: You may also need to use the ^ to match at the beginning: `%^site.com/[A-Z]+/?$%`

Answer (score 0):

Just put a '$' at the end of your regex pattern. It means end of string

```
site.com/[a-zA-Z]/$
```

You can use www.debuggex.com to check out the regex.